# T and D flip flop - > pin

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, pinout

I have found many projects(digital timers) which use D and T flip flops.

In the left bottom pin we put the clock source, can this pin be always high or always low?
And if that's possible writing data to flip flop or toggling values is always when that pin is high correct?

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally a *clock* is *edge* triggered.

A level-driven "causer of change" would tend to be an "asynchronous load" (if it accepts arbitrary data) or a "set" or "reset"/"clear" if it is both the cause of change and the resulting state.

To understand the details of your particular part, please refer to its data sheet.  That's really where you should start with something like this anyway.  If there's a specific aspect of the data sheet which is unclear, then asking about that makes a much better question.